# Break and continue Node.js readline async for loop

Tags: node.js

I'm using the Node.js readline interface to read a file line-by-line using an async for-of loop. But I want to be able to control the flow and I'm not sure how to break and continue the loop where it left off.

Simplified example:

```
  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('input.txt')

  const  rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fileStream,
    crlfDelay: Infinity
  })

 for await (const line of rl) {
   console.log(line) // This works
   break
 }

 for await (const line of rl) {
   console.log(line) // This does not print anything
 }
```

See this [replit](https://repl.it/@christilut/linereader-await#index.js) for a complete example.

How do I use the same readline interface to continue the loop where it left off?

Answer (score 0):

Async generators close the underlying stream once you exit the loop. So I went for this instead:

```
    const it = this.lineReader[Symbol.asyncIterator]()

    while (true) {
      const res = await it.next()
      if (res.done) break
      line = res.value.trim()
    }
```